# Persisting Knowledge Session in Drools

Tags: jpa, persistence, marshalling, drools, unmarshalling

Objective: I want to persist/re-use a drools knowledge session once created for firing rules again.

Problem: I want to create a knowledge session using decision table with over 10 thousand rules. Creating this session and disposing it off every time is not feasible and I want to store the session once created which can be identified by a key and re-use this session over and again.
I already tried drools' jpa knowledge service and kie's marshaling, but neither of the two worked. It required an instance of KnowledgeBase and creating a new instance of knowledgebase with the drools table every time is not desirable for my use case as it is taking quite some time. How do I store id of knowledge base created and use it to retrieve this base later? Or how do I persist my kSession without this information of kbase?

**EDIT**: We have a set of rules where we need to compare current data to an old data set for deciding value of a parameter for new data.
The old data set is huge and changes only once a month. Currently, the way we're approaching this is to have a rule for each row in the old data. This is very slow to load and we've to do this once for a request and fire rules iteratively for each entry in current data set. The solution you gave works. So now, I don't have to load again and again which solves my purpose. But if I come to think about it, it doesn't seem to be the best solution.
Another approach that I am trying is, to insert the old data set as facts in the session and then persist the session. Next time when I load the session I'll have the facts available with me and I can use that to fire my rules. Do you think this approach is better? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'd need some sort of sample data & more details. - Once there was a DT to determine insurance premium rates based on 4 or 5 fields, varying values in severals steps, exercising all combinations to test for equality with one specifc set. Resulted in (IIRC) 50,000 rows - too slow. Inserting the data as facts was indeed the solution. And I don't think you'd have to marshal the session with these facts. Unmarshalling them from whatever form (Object*Stream or even XML) you have them should be fast enough, because inserts against a small number of rules shouldn't be slow.

Comment: The scenario is we have three fields, let's suppose the fields to be location, age and discount. That accounts for some 50 thousand rows of old data. Now, if the location & age of our new data matches the previous values we set the discount of new data to that of old data. For this, I need to compare each entry of new data to the list of old data and set the discount accordingly. How do you suggest I go about that? Please let me know if you need any further further information.

Comment: That's very much like the scenario I was describing. Execution time depends on the speed you can get the data for the 50,000 objects into memory, i.e., i/o time. 50000 inserts and 1000 firings are so fast it's not worth timing.

Comment: I tried it with insertion of multiple facts and it worked for me. The process is relatively super-fast and it achievable without persisting the session. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A good way for fast startup is to save the KieBase to a file and read it whenever required.

```
    KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
    FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream( KBPATH );
    ObjectOutputStream oos1 = new ObjectOutputStream( fos1 );
    oos1.writeObject( kieBase );
    oos1.close();
```

---

```
    FileInputStream fis9 = new FileInputStream( KBPATH );
    ObjectInputStream ois9 = new ObjectInputStream( fis9 );
    KieBase kieBase = (KieBase)ois9.readObject();
    KieSession kieSession = kieBase.newKieSession();
```

(However, a decision table with over 10,000 rules just doesn't seem the right way of using Drools. Not only compiling may be slow - how does this perform with inserts?)

**Later** Based on the simple situation you've added to your question, I do recommend to insert the row data as facts and then use one rule

```
rule "update discount"
when
  $op: OldPerson( $oloc: location, $oage: age, $odis: discount )
  $np: NewPerson( location == $oloc, age == $oage, discount != $odis )
then
  modify( $np ){ setDiscount( $odis ) }
end
```

Not worth persisting anything; use any file format for old and new persons; probably not even worth zipping.